# Using dingbats in CSS/SASS comments

Tags: css, sass, comments, semantics, unsemantic-css

I just had the idea of adding some visual distinction to my CSS/SASS comments so that I can notice them quicker when I rush trough a pile of files that I am currently working on. So I thought, why not use **[dingbats](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2700-27BF)**, you don't see stuff like that in your code, so why not start using it?

For example this cross dingbat here:

[image] [image]

[image]

My question - is it semantically wrong to use **dingbats** in CSS/SASS or JS or whatever code comments it is in that manner?

SASS doesn't seem to mind this. Page loads neatly as well.

[image]

> Not for people with **OCD** though.

Comment: @Vucko , I am referring to the cross-looking dingbat icon in the commented section. Is a dingbat css-parsable?

Comment: I misunderstood you OP. Well, what do you get when SASS precompiles?

Comment: The same output as the SASS input.

Comment: My take on this is that it's only "*wrong*" if you are abiding by a certain coding style guide which specifies a certain format or rules against comments of this style. If not, go wild ;)